# image view:second image is replaced by the first image captured

Tags: android, imageview, onactivityresult, android-afilechooser

hello i am struck in this coding first of all i am having two image view's when we click one of them the chooser dialog box will open which is having two option 1.take photo 2.select from gallery when i select from galley everything is working fine where as the problem is,

when we select take photo option and after we had captured the image when setting its preview for the first image its working fine where as the problem here is in the second image. when we select take photo option and after capturing the photo it is replacing the image of the first image with the second image.

This is Java Code:

```
public class PrescriptionUpload extends ActionBarActivity {
    ImageView uploadimage1, uploadimage2;
    Bitmap imagemap, imagemapsec;
    int imageupload = 1;
    int imagesecpload = 2;
    int requestcamera = 0;
    Button uploadpric;
    StringBuilder sb;
    String uploadimg2;
    Toolbar include2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.prescriptionimages);
        include2= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.include2);
        setSupportActionBar(include2);
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        uploadimage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.uploadimage1);
        uploadimage1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectimage(imageupload);
            }
        });
        uploadimage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.uploadimage2);
        uploadimage2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectimage(imagesecpload);
            }
        });
    }



    private void selectimage(final int number) {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PrescriptionUpload.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Prescription");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, requestcamera);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                            number);
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            if (requestCode == imageupload) {
                try {
                    imagemap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
                    uploadimage1.setImageBitmap(imagemap);
                    uploadimage2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else if (requestCode == imagesecpload) {
                try {
                    imagemapsec = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
                    uploadimage2.setImageBitmap(imagemapsec);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else if (requestCode == requestcamera) {


               if (uploadimage1.getId()==R.id.uploadimage1){

                    Bitmap testurl = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    uploadimage1.setImageBitmap(testurl);
                    uploadimage2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else if (uploadimage2.getId()==R.id.uploadimage2){
                    Bitmap testurltwo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    uploadimage2.setImageBitmap(testurltwo);

              }


            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: save first image in temporary folder then set to Image view  same second image to Temp folder  then set to the image view.....

Comment: you are handling wrong condition, when u receive image ===> if (uploadimage1.getId()==R.id.uploadimage1) this condition always true that's why image always set to first image view.

Comment: Maintain a flag on like "isFirstImage" something like that and mange image setting in "OnActivityResult()".

Comment: i also tried to write the condition reverse also

Comment: temporary folder means?

Comment: i think we cant use flag on the image view na?

Comment: help me out friends plz not able to understand what to do

Answer (score 0):

i had solved my problem using onActivityResult and with the increment of the variable